# Does Salesforce have an Antivirus feature?

Tags: security, appexchange

Is there any way to integrate Antivirus in Salesforce, or does this already exist?

Additionally, I would like to also have realtime URL scanning of malicious HTML documents and websites.

Key features I want to block include EXEs in ZIP files, malicious PDFs and basic document scanning (DOC, DOCX, etc)

Answer (score 11):

As of now, Salesforce does not do any anti-virus scanning. However, there is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IoG6) here which is under point threshold. Until this is implemented you can use 3rd party apps from AppExchange such as [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wTlNEAU) one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't address your primary concern head-on, but it is possible to block certain file types from being uploaded. There is not, however, a built-in antivirus or file scanning tool.

There are currently two features you can explore to prevent certain file types from being uploaded into Salesforce.

## File Upload and Download Security Settings

Under Setup > Security > File Upload and Download Security there is a checkbox that you can check, ["Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_type_security.htm&type=5), to prevent the following file types from being uploaded as attachments and documents:

- html
- htt
- mht
- svg
- thtml
- xhtml

This of course is fairly limited, your main concern is likely around executables. For that there is,

## File Trigger

With some Apex code it's possible to prevent `ContentVersion`, `Attachment`, and `FeedItem` records from being inserted into your org. Your trigger would look something like below (adapted from [Salesforce help 000319977](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319977&type=1&mode=1)):

```java
trigger RestrictFile on FeedItem (after insert) {

    Map<Id, FeedItem> contentversionIdToFeedItemMap = new Map<Id, FeedItem>();
    
    for(FeedItem fi : trigger.new){
        if(fi.type == 'ContentPost') {
            contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.put(fi.RelatedRecordId, fi);
        }
    }

    for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT Id, FileExtension,FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN :contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.keySet()]) {
        if(cv.FileType == 'png') {
            contentversionIdToFeedItemMap.get(cv.Id).addError('File having this extension could not be attached,Please try some other extension.');
        }
    }  
}
```

## Communities/Experience Cloud

I feel it's also worth mentioning this setting that's available in each Experience Cloud Site, particularly because a public-facing site is a much more likely attack vector. When you create a site, under Administration > Preferences, there is a section labeled **Files** that will allow you to restrict files based on size and file extension. Enter your file extensions separated with commas to exclude them. The periods are optional, per the help text.

[image: Allow only these file types setting in Experience Cloud]